# I have deployed vue-cli app to gh pages. Loading ok. But after refreshing a 404-error occurs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have made an app based on vue-cli 3 and vue-router, deployed it to gh pages and saved the link. When I click on the link, the app loads normal. But if I click on refresh/reload, a 404-error occurs.
My link: https://alexandrchek.github.io/filmrock/index.html

I tried to find the answer in the net. But I have not find a description of the same problem. There are no descriptions of problems with refreshing.
Why does it happen? Help me to fix this problem, please.

Comment: Give up on GH, and give a try to [Netlify](https://netlify.com/). Treat yourself, will be faster, simpler, and still free.

Comment: I agree with Kissu, way less headaches using netlify. 
Are you using a bundler for you site? If you check the console, even if the page loads it still throws a 404 error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I use webpack. Maybe Netlify would solve the problem. But our employers like GH. So I find another way. I changed the **history: createWebHistory()** for **history: createWebHashHistory()** in the settings of router. Now the app works. It`s acceptable for a portfolio.

Comment: Your employers are not actually working on the website, their opinion should be secondary. You'll ask them for some debugging down the road.

Comment: Unfortunately at the stage of job search their opinion is primery))

Comment: Showing that you know something more adapted is also quite a nice thing overall. Expertise gets you hired.